# Cannot connect to Kafka over SSL from Internet, but works from within the Kafka pod

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have deployed Kafka [strimzi](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/configuring.html) to my Kubernetes cluster.

My goal is to be able to connect to Kafka topic over SSL listener(port 9094) and be able to produce/consume messages.

### Symptoms

```
[2022-05-05 10:20:11,252] ERROR Error when sending message to topic public.kafka.incoming.events with key: null, value: 4 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic public.kafka.incoming.events not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

The message is not effectively sent by the producer or received by the consumer.

logs of strimzi-cluster-operator pod when selecting loadbalancer or ingress as type (i.e.: `kafka.listeners.external.type`).

```
failed to reconcile ZookeeperScalingException: Failed to connect to Zookeeper my-cluster-zookeeper-0.my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.my-kafka-project.svc:2181. Connection was not ready in 300000 ms.
```

Not sure if this is related with my Kubernetes cluster configuration problem. When I select NodePort - it works as expected and kafka + zookeper are started normally.

To make this story short, I have:

##### 1. Activated the debugging flag:

`log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO` -> `log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=DEBUG`

and I am able to read the logs from Kafka server.

##### 2. Configured/generated the signed certificate, keystore/truststore JKs and the configuration I use looks like:

```
cat <<EOT > ssl.properties
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
bootstrap.servers=my-cluster-kafka-external-bootstrap:9094
ssl.truststore.location=/home/kafka/user-truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<password>
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/user-keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=<password>
ssl.key.password=<password>
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
EOT
```

##### 3. Distinctions between case #1 which works and case #2 which does not work and is why I am asking this question.

1. Case 1: This is the case which works normally, I am connecting to Kafka topics from within the pod which is running Kafka server.
2. Case 2: In the second case, which is not working as expected, the connecting goes to a **load-balancer**(i.e which is exposed to the internet).
   The load-balancer connection is then established through a **private network** (10.20.10.0/24) which communicates with the Kubernetes cluster.

#### Case 1 (which works, and is why I have put here to help solve this problem)

Testing from a Kafka server pod (within the cluster).

*Producer*

```
[kafka@my-cluster-kafka-0 ~]$ /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server my-cluster-kafka-external-bootstrap:9094 --topic public.kafka.incoming.events --producer.config consumer-ssl.properties 
>ttesttt
>
```

*Consumer*

```
[kafka@my-cluster-kafka-0 ~]$ /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server my-cluster-kafka-0.my-cluster-kafka-brokers.my-kafka-project.svc.cluster.local:9094 --topic public.kafka.incoming.events --consumer.config consumer-ssl.properties
ttesttt
```

*Confirmation*

Confirmation based on the Kafka server logs.

- When a Producer is connecting successfully

```
2022-05-05 13:40:07,988 DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.15.19.76:9094-xx.xxx.xx4.xx7:45150-42 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.15.19.76:9094 remote=/xx.xxx.xx4.xx7:45150], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5c2628ee, interestOps=1, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'xx.xxx.xx4.xx7' peerPort 45150 peerPrincipal 'CN=my-user' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12]
2022-05-05 13:40:07,989 DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Successfully authenticated with /xx.xxx.xx4.xx7 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12]
```

- When a Consumer is connecting successfully

```
2022-05-05 13:43:56,053 DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.15.19.76:9094-10.15.19.76:40094-43 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.15.19.76:9094 remote=/10.15.19.76:40094], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7df0ddcc, interestOps=1, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost '10.15.19.76' peerPort 40094 peerPrincipal 'CN=my-user' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-10]
2022-05-05 13:43:56,053 DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Successfully authenticated with /10.15.19.76 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-10]
2022-05-05 13:43:56,323 DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.15.19.76:9094-xx.xxx.xx4.xx7:1270-43 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.15.19.76:9094 remote=/xx.xxx.xx4.xx7:1270], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@323eac4e, interestOps=1, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'xx.xxx.xx4.xx7' peerPort 1270 peerPrincipal 'CN=my-user' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-11]
2022-05-05 13:43:56,323 DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Successfully authenticated with /xx.xxx.xx4.xx7 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-11]
2022-05-05 13:43:56,335 INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Dynamic member with unknown member id joins group console-consumer-27420 in Empty state. Created a new member id console-consumer-f9cb320c-a5cf-4e40-a686-6dbd1d37cdd6 and request the member to rejoin with this id. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator) [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-3]
2022-05-05 13:43:56,340 INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group console-consumer-27420 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-26) (reason: Adding new member console-consumer-f9cb320c-a5cf-4e40-a686-6dbd1d37cdd6 with group instance id None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator) [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-6]
2022-05-05 13:43:59,342 INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group console-consumer-27420 generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-26) with 1 members (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator) [executor-Rebalance]
2022-05-05 13:43:59,359 INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader console-consumer-f9cb320c-a5cf-4e40-a686-6dbd1d37cdd6 for group console-consumer-27420 for generation 1. The group has 1 members, 0 of which are static. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator) [data-plane-kafka-request-handler-7]
2022-05-05 13:43:59,468 DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.15.19.76:9094-xx.xxx.xx4.xx7:1584-43 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.15.19.76:9094 remote=/xx.xxx.xx4.xx7:1584], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5c2628ee, interestOps=1, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'xx.xxx.xx4.xx7' peerPort 1584 peerPrincipal 'CN=my-user' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12]
2022-05-05 13:43:59,468 DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Successfully authenticated with /xx.xxx.xx4.xx7 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12]
```

#### Case 2 (which does not work, and is why I am asking this question)

Testing from my local machine (connecting through Internet).

*Producer*

```
$ /opt/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server internet-reachable-domain-name:9094 --topic public.kafka.incoming.events --producer.config consumer-ssl.properties 
....long SSL/TLS hand-shake....
)
ttesttttt
javax.net.ssl|ALL|16|kafka-producer-network-thread | console-producer|2022-05-05 10:05:04.469 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
```

Notice how the character '**>**' is not getting displayed on the first line.

*Consumer*

```
$ /opt/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server internet-reachable-domain-name:9094 --topic public.kafka.incoming.events --consumer.config consumer-ssl.properties 
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2022-05-05 10:08:29.034 EDT|Finished.java:535|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 6A 3A 3D F6 87 81 A0 36   FF 08 77 CB 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 10:08:37.815 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 10:08:48.159 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 10:09:06.713 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 10:09:37.193 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 10:10:11.936 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
```

Note how the message is not reaching, and even if I type a message from a Producer of the Case #1, its not showing on this consumer.

*Confirmation*

Confirmation based on the Kafka server logs.

- When a Producer is connecting

```
2022-05-05 14:14:43,507 DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.15.19.76:9094-10.15.30.64:19952-46 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.15.19.76:9094 remote=/10.15.30.64:19952], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@5c2628ee, interestOps=1, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost '10.15.30.64' peerPort 19952 peerPrincipal 'CN=my-user' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12]
2022-05-05 14:14:43,507 DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Successfully authenticated with /10.15.30.64 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-12]
```

- When a Consumer is connecting

```
2022-05-05 14:16:02,620 DEBUG [SslTransportLayer channelId=10.15.19.76:9094-10.15.219.64:42153-47 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.15.19.76:9094 remote=/10.15.219.64:42153], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@7df0ddcc, interestOps=1, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost '10.15.219.64' peerPort 42153 peerPrincipal 'CN=my-user' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-10]
2022-05-05 14:16:02,621 DEBUG [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Successfully authenticated with /10.15.219.64 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector) [data-plane-kafka-network-thread-0-ListenerName(EXTERNAL-9094)-SSL-10]
```

*Other information*

I am using the option:

`export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose"`

to get more information from Kafka clients.
This is what I can see from the producer in case #2.

```
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:54:50.374 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:55:23.285 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:55:48.477 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:56:13.718 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:56:50.532 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:57:25.793 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:58:01.707 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:58:30.806 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2022-05-05 09:59:07.867 EDT|SSLEngineImpl.java:752|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
```

#### Kafka version

Both clients are identical:

```
# Local device
$ /opt/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
3.1.0 (Commit:37edeed0777bacb3)

# Kafka server pod
$ /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
3.1.0 (Commit:37edeed0777bacb3)
```

Comment: Kafka client protocol cannot use load balancers, only the bootstrap connection can.. Clients must connect to each individual broker ,which is returned by the individual pod's advertised listeners settings (which I'm guessing you aren't allowing over the internet). So, make sure that that **those are routable** and you can individual target each of them without using the load balancer

Comment: You are right, this also means that TLS/SSL has nothing to do with this issue.Sure, I'll dig in how to make those routable - but I am not sure yet how to achieve that.

Comment: This page goes over setting external DNS names and per-broker loadbalancers. https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/05/13/accessing-kafka-part-4/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) for the information.

The links you provided were the exact one I had to look. The problem was that Ingress option or Load-Balancer did not work on my Kubernetes Cluster, Kafka was not starting. Only nodePort option worked, but that was not sufficient to address the problem I had.

I ended up using bitnami instead of strimzi, https://bitnami.com/stack/kafka/helm and it worked like charm.

I relied on the example provided by [@Rubber Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447071/rubber-duck) on [Accessing bitnami/kafka outside the kubernetes cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473341/accessing-bitnami-kafka-outside-the-kubernetes-cluster)

I just had to make sure to forward the ports by the load-balancer.

###### command:

```
helm install kafka-bitnami --values bitnami-values-external.yaml bitnami/kafka
```

###### file: bitnami-values-external.yaml

```
replicaCount: 3
externalAccess:
  enabled: true
  autoDiscovery:
    enabled: false
    image:
      registry: docker.io
      repository: bitnami/kubectl
      tag: 1.23.4-debian-10-r17
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      pullSecrets: []
    resources:
      limits: {}
      requests: {}
  service:
    type: NodePort
    port: 9094
    loadBalancerIPs: []
    loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
    nodePorts:
      - 30000
      - 30001
      - 30002
    useHostIPs: false
    annotations: {}
    domain: <domain-name which points to my load-balancer public IP>
```

Note that `replicaCount` must much the number of `nodePorts` items.

###### load balancer configs

The load balancer config will have something like:

```
frontend-1 port: 30000 -> backend-1 port: 30000, server ips: [set of private worker node ips]
frontend-1 port: 30001 -> backend-1 port: 30001, server ips: [set of private worker node ips]
frontend-1 port: 30002 -> backend-1 port: 30002, server ips: [set of private worker node ips]
```

Maybe from here, I could come back to strimzi and try to adjust/fix it because I understand little bit better how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/) is a great platform to run Kafka on Kubernetes. As you haven't shared the kafka CR file, I am assuming you have done the following setup to access Kafka from outside the k8s cluster-

```
# ...
listeners:
# ...
  - name: external
    port: 9094
    type: loadbalancer
    tls: true
# ...
```

Make sure you have resources like the below-
[image]

With this configuration and proper Authn/Authz, you would be able to access  Kafka from outside the k8s cluster.
Check this [article](https://medium.com/@singh.amarendra/kafka-on-kubernetes-using-strimzi-part-5-security-fc878178cd04) (PS - written by me), which takes a dig on how to enable Authn/Authz in Strimzi and it also discusses Accessing Kafka from inside the k8s cluster and from outside of it.

Comment: When I select loadbalancer as type, or even ingress, the kafka pods would not start as expected.


Added these details in the question: logs of strimzi-cluster-operator pod when selecting loadbalancer or ingress as type (i.e.: `kafka.listeners.external.type`).
```
failed to reconcile ZookeeperScalingException: Failed to connect to Zookeeper my-cluster-zookeeper-0.my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes.my-kafka-project.svc:2181. Connection was not ready in 300000 ms.
```
Not sure if this is related with my Kubernetes cluster configuration problem.